# How to programmatically find the number of cpu sockets and core per socket in Linux C

Tags: c, linux

Although what I want on the surface might look like it has been answered here before, what I am looking for is finding the number of cpu sockets and cores per socket **NOT** the total number of CPUS. So using `get_nprocs_conf()` is not enough for my purposes.

Currently I can get this info by parsing `lscpu` through forking and calling execl or execv but my problems are;

- Calling a terminal command is not secure, even when I fork and use exec* family functions (execv, execl etc.).
- Makes my code overly reliant on the formatting of `lscpu`, hence any changes in the output, will have ramifications on my code.
- `lscpu` might not exist in some of the target systems that my code is going to be executed in.

Here is a sample output of `lscpu` and what I parse from it denoted by <-

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6 <- I need this
Socket(s):           1 <- and this
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             3797.808
CPU max MHz:         4600,0000
CPU min MHz:         800,0000
BogoMIPS:            6384.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cm
ov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb
rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop
_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx
 est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt ts
c_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault
 invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid e
pt_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed ad
x smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pt
s hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

So essentially what I am looking for is a more elegant and secure way of finding sockets and cores per socket. Is there a way I can do this or do I have to stick to parsing lscpu?

Comment: The source for the `lscpu` command should be readily available for you to read and check how it fetches the values you seek.

Comment: In case you're wondering [it uses `/proc/cpuinfo`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/lscpu.c).

Comment: yeah, was already doing it before I wrote this question but I was wondering if a shortcut existed that I was not aware of.

Comment: ty for the suggestions though

Comment: You\`ll have to read `sysfs`. Under Linux there is hardly any other way.

This is what you need to get started: [How CPU topology info is exported via `sysfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/cputopology.rst).

Comment: alright I'll take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It also looks like similar information is available from [dmidecode](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c). You need privileges to read the tables, however. And dmidecode is only available on x86 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few API calls that provide such information at various level. If you just need the count of CPUs, `get_nprocs`, `get_nprocs_conf`, or `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);` will work.

If you need more details (core per sockets, etc), consider parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`, which is less expensive than running external process `lscpu`. Remember that in virtual environment, the breakdown into sockets, etc, may not be as important as it is in physical servers.

Comment: The question specifically says that "get_nprocs_conf" is not useful.